# Password sometimes not recognized after Ubuntu locks

Tags: login, password, lock-screen

Sometimes, after Ubuntu's "Blank Screen" power saving thing activates and I'm prompted to enter my password, my password will just not be recognized. This has been happening for months at least but it used to be rare enough so I didn't care. Now it happens at least once a day, so it's becoming pretty annoying.

After I enter my password correctly, it simply says "Incorrect password, please try again". Caps is not enabled and I'm using the correct keyboard. However, I've noticed that it happens more often (or always?) when power saving mode activates while I'm using a Russian keyboard layout. In the password prompt it says that the English keyboard is activated and it doesn't matter which layout I switch to, the password will only be recognized after I restart the computer. I can log into tty1 just fine and I've tried deleting the .Xauthority file, with no results.

Edit: I am using Ubuntu 17.10, Gnome and Lightdm

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you running? Have you done `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` recently?

Comment: @AndroidDev 17.10  - I upgraded about a month ago.

Comment: A lot of packages change and many bugs are squashed in a month... (not to mention all the security holes patched) I would strongly recommend you upgrade.

Comment: @AndroidDev I obviously keep my system up to date and install updates whenever they are available... And as I've said in my question, the issue has existed for months at least (probably closer to a year)